# Optimizing a parallel implementation of a list comprehension

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a dataframe, where each row contains a list of integers. I also have a reference-list that I use to check what integers in the dataframe appear in this list.

I have made two implementations of this, one single-threaded and one multi-threaded. The single-threaded implementation is quite fast (takes roughly 0.1s on my machine), whereas the multithreaded takes roughly 5s.

My question is: Is this due to my implementation being poor, or is this merely a case where the overhead due to multithreading is so large that it doesn't make sense to use multiple threads?

The example is below:

```
import time
from random import randint
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

class A:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.ls = [[randint(0, 99) for i in range(20)] for j in range(N)]
        self.ls = pd.DataFrame({'col': self.ls})

        self.lst_nums = [randint(0, 99) for i in range(999)]

    @classmethod
    def helper(cls, lst_nums, col):
        return any([s in lst_nums for s in col])

    def get_idx_method1(self):
        method1 = self.ls['col'].apply(lambda nums: any(x in self.lst_nums for x in nums))
        return method1

    def get_idx_method2(self):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
        method2 = pool.map(partial(A.helper, self.lst_nums), self.ls['col'])
        pool.close()
        return method2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = A(50000)

    start = time.time()
    m1 = a.get_idx_method1()
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)

    start = time.time()
    m2 = a.get_idx_method2()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, multiprocessing is useful when the cost of data communication between the main process and the others is less comparable to the time cost of the function.

Another thing is that you made an error in your code:

```
def helper(cls, lst_nums, col):
    return any([s in lst_nums for s in col])
```

VS

```
any(x in self.lst_nums for x in nums)
```

You have that list [] in the helper method, which will make the any() method to wait for the entire array to be computed, while the second any() will just stop at the first True value.

In conclusion if you remove list brackets from the helper method and maybe increase the randint range for lst_nums initializer, you will notice an increase in speed when using multiple processes.

```
self.lst_nums = [randint(0, 10000) for i in range(999)]
```

and

```
def helper(cls, lst_nums, col):
    return any(s in lst_nums for s in col)
```